# How to properly inject a DbContext for WebAPI using a ContextFactory and a repository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I'm trying to safely inject a database context per web request for a repository on the back of a Web API. The consuming class calls the repository in order to retrieve the object, and if it comes back null, then it gets the object from a different data store and saves that in the database for faster access later. This means it's trying to Get from the DB then doing stuff then creating a new record.

Currently I have this repository

```
public class OrganisationRepository : IOrganisationRepository
{
    public Func<IOrganisationDomainDbContext> ContextFactory { get; set; }

    public Organisation GetDetailByIdentifier(int id)
    {
        using (var context = ContextFactory.Invoke())
        {
            var org = context.Organisations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            return org;
        }
    }

    public void Create(Organisation orgToCreate)
    {
        using (var context = ContextFactory.Invoke())
        {
            context.Organisations.Add(orgToCreate);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

and the repository is injected into the consuming class with a transient lifestyle. The DbContext is injected per web request.

Previously, the Repository was injected with a singleton lifestyle, which was breaking on the Create action.

My question is, am I doing a cheap hack by making the Repository transient? Will this cause me problems down the line? If so, how should I be doing this differently?

EDIT: For further information, the DI Container in use is Castle Windsor
EDIT: Relevant parts of the DI Installer

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IOrganisationDomainDbContext>().ImplementedBy<OrganisationDomainDbContext>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest, 
                Component.For<Func<IOrganisationDomainDbContext>>().Instance(container.Resolve<IOrganisationDomainDbContext>), 
                Component.For<IOrganisationRepository>().ImplementedBy<OrganisationRepository>().LifeStyle.Transient, 
                Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        }
```

**UPDATE:** Transient repository did not fix the problem, that was a mistake on my part - I just forgot that the record I was looking at had in fact been committed to the database, and therefore the create action was not being called.  My mistake, apologies.

Comment: Why did the repository break on `Create` when it was a Singleton?

Comment: Hi Mark, it was an InvalidOperationException, as the DbContext had already been disposed

Comment: Doesn't `ContextFactory.Invoke()` create a new `DbContext` every time it's called?

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but it doesn't appear to be working properly. It gets to 'context.Organisations.Add(orgToCreate)' and throws the exception.

Comment: How is that factory implemented?

Comment: If the DbContext is injected per WebRequest, you should not handle its lifetime with a `using`. (ie don't wrap `var context = ContextFactory.Invoke()`in a using)

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'm a little bit vague on how the factory is implemented, but in the Windsor Installer, IDbContext is implemented by DbContext, and Func<IDbContext> is assigned an instance of DbContext (via resolving IDbContext). So, as far as I'm aware, ContextFactory.Invoke is *supposed* to create a new instance of DbContext, but it doesn't - I guess because the lifestyle of the context is per web request and it has already been disposed? I'm unsure whether using a single instance throughout the repository would get disposed correctly - does PerWebRequest ensure this for me?

Comment: Could you please show the code (edit your question) instead of explaining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user jbl pointed out, I didn't need to use using blocks around the context usage - the DI Container disposes of the context as it is used per web request.

Here's the code now:

```
public class OrganisationRepository : IOrganisationRepository
{
    public Func<IOrganisationDomainDbContext> ContextFactory { get; set; }

    public Organisation GetDetailByIdentifier(int id)
    {
        var context = ContextFactory.Invoke()
        var org = context.Organisations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return org;
    }

    public void Create(Organisation orgToCreate)
    {
        var context = ContextFactory.Invoke();
        context.Organisations.Add(orgToCreate);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And the DI container installer:

```
container.Register(
            Component.For<IOrganisationDomainDbContext>().ImplementedBy<OrganisationDomainDbContext>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest, 
            Component.For<Func<IOrganisationDomainDbContext>>().Instance(container.Resolve<IOrganisationDomainDbContext>), 
            Component.For<IOrganisationRepository>().ImplementedBy<OrganisationRepository>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest, 
            Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Hopefully this is the correct answer, debugging shows that the contexts are disposed of after each web request and I'm not running into the exceptions. Thanks for all the help jbl and Mark Seeman.